# Framework PHP Route - Error 404 Not found

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, http-status-code-404

In Laravel, I need to edit user created by Auth/RegisterController, but using the controller that I created, example ProfileController. But when I try access by a a:href button, show 404 Error.

Code:

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
    Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController')->except(['edit']);
    Route::get('profile/{profile}/edit', ['as' => 'profile.edit', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@edit']);
});

Auth::routes();
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{route('profile.edit',['profile'=>auth()->user()->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary">
                        {{auth()->user()->email}}
</a>
```

**ProfileController**

```
public function edit($profile)
{
   $user = \App\User::findOrFail($profile);
   return view('profile.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

**List Routes**

```
|        | POST      | profile                | profile.store    | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@store                           | web,auth,guest                  |      
|        | GET|HEAD  | profile                | profile.index    | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@index                           | web,auth,guest                  |      
|        | GET|HEAD  | profile/create         | profile.create   | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@create                          | web,auth,guest                  |      
|        | DELETE    | profile/{profile}      | profile.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@destroy                         | web,auth,guest                  |      
|        | PUT|PATCH | profile/{profile}      | profile.update   | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@update                          | web,auth,guest                  |      
|        | GET|HEAD  | profile/{profile}      | profile.show     | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@show                            | web,auth,guest                  |      
|        | GET|HEAD  | profile/{profile}/edit | profile.edit     | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@edit                            | web,auth,guest                  |
```

Someone can help me?

Tks,

*Aguiar, Adson M.*

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you know the resource would have registered the same exact `edit` route for you?  also are you using `App\User` for authentication?

Comment: It's weird that your routes have both auth and guest middleware applied... are you sure you are logged in and have an auth()->user()?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Like @lagbox mentioned, you can just keep the

```
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController');
```

without the `->except()` to have the exact same edit route automatically generated for you.

Furthermore, you can simplify your controller action to:

```
public function edit(User $profile)
{
   return view('profile.edit', compact('profile'));
}
```

This uses type hinting to automatically have the dependency injection resolve a User instance for you, identified by the key passed in with the {profile} parameter.

You would then have to go with `$profile` in your profile/edit.blade.php, unless you want to do something like `return view('profile.edit', ['user' => $profile]);`.

It might be a good idea to name the parameters like your Models. Resource routes usually base completely on the Model's names, so profile is not a good choice for User routes. You might either use `Route::resource('user', 'ProfileController')` (or even UserController for that matter), or if you want to stick with profile, but want `$user` as a parameter, you would have to create all routes by yourself like `Route::get('profile/{user}/edit', 'ProfileController')`.

Also, writing `route('profile.edit',['profile'=>auth()->user()])` works too, and has the advantage that it would not break when the user is not authenticated.

All that said, your code should still work. Try to use a `find()` instead of a `findOrFail()` and `dd($user);` in the following line to make sure your route is working. If you see the dump, it is probably null, meaning the id passed is not valid, which would be really odd.

If you can post the full generated link of the anchor tag and the outcome of the `dd`, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Ok. In a first time, I tried using UserController and simple Route::resource, but not work.  I did it what you mentioned and the result was the same. I added the dd to the UserController in the edit call, but nothing was exibed.

Comment: If you replaced the firestOrFail with first and the dd as I mentioned, and you are still getting a 404, your link might not be correct. Can you please put a @dd(route('profile.edit', ['profile'=>auth()->user()->id])) in your app.blade.php and post the output here?

Comment: I don't know why, but resolved this issue executing the command "php artisan make:controller UserController --resource" and past the code in the new controller. Thanks for all.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear. That's why you should always post complete code and not just tiny parts of it. ;-)